# PHP PDO Select that specify column while using the while loop to fetch all data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let me explain a bit about the project I am working on so it will be more clear; I have a recovery system where user puts in his email + message and then he simply clicks recover.

The system generates a random string and creates him an account with his email, that ID, + his message.
In mySQL I have auto_Inc row called user_ID and it's my primary key.

Now, I have a admin panel where I see all of the recover requests, like this:

```
<email address>, <ID>, <User_Id>

rtemkller@gmail.com CF3E75381E  5
artemk1ller@gmail.com CE783351FE 4
ferrarihc@aol.com CE58E37F13 3
ferrarihc@aol.com E375318CEF 2
multi@multi.com 8EC5F7133E 1
```

This is the code I use:

```
    $fetch = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
    $fetch->execute();

    while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
        echo $row['email'].'  '.$row['id'].' <br />';
    }
```

Now, I want to add a new link, to view the message like this:

```
ferrarihc@aol.com E375318CEF 2 View Message
```

When you click on 'View message', it will go to the row of the email `Farrarihc@aol.com` and then I can fetch the message of it, and anything I want that is stored in that column.

*Thing is, I've never done this or thought on how to do this.*

**Question**

How do I make that link go to the specify email?

My problem: I don't know what is the email, `cause I'm using a loop to get all results`.
If I don't know what is the email, how will I find out it's column?

```
I am new to PHP, PDO, pretty much hehe.
```

Comment: Ajax seems pretty harder, well it's syntax, but I am not looking to make this script look good, It's all about practising, I am not very good at learning multiple languages at same time, that's very bad.

Comment: Does a link like `<a href="details.php?email=foo@example.com">` ring any bells?

Comment: Can you then provide the table schemas?

Comment: @Deceze I'm using a loop to get all results. If I don't know what is the email, how will I find out it's column?

Comment: You *are* printing the email! Print it in a link such as the above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use anchor tag in which you can pass location as `href="<?php echo "yoururl/email?$email?>"`. Now when user click on that url he will be redirected to that page. On that page you can get the `$_get['email']`. And By using this email you can get the details from datbase.
Simple!

Comment: I hope you know how to use where condintion

Comment: But the problem is, I don't know the email..

Comment: What you mean by that you dont know email

Comment: I am using a while loop, to loop ALL of the results in the table, every, and when you click 'View message' it will go to that specify message.

Comment: That is what I am saying, For this pass this email as search term and search from database where this email matches